# Удалились файлы в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

В visual studio code нажал во вкладке система управления версиями отменить все изменения и в итоге у меня просто удалились файлы проекта который был открыт, есть ли возможность вернуть эти файлы?

Comment: дайте вопросу нормальный заголовок

Comment: @Эникейщик, заголовок гораздо лучше, чем в той истории на гитхабе. А текст ещё лучше.

Comment: @Эникейщик, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32405

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33235338/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy напоминает [историю с rm -rf](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/issues/123) :D

Comment: Но заголовок стоит уточнить в любом случае. Типа "Удалились файлы после отмены изменений в VS Code"

Comment: @dIm0n, ну с rm действительно косяк скрипта, а тут человек сам жмёт кнопочку "я хочу всё уничтожить (и это необратимо)".

Comment: а откат к коммиту с определенным id уже невозможен?

Comment: @S.H., если там был репозиторий, то, конечно, возможен. А если не было, то и коммитов не было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Предупреждение надо было читать.
2. Нет, только утилитами для поиска удалённых файлов на диске.

Comment: я запомню это на всю жизнь, у меня удалилось почти все, что я делал с самого начала своего обучения, при чем некоторые проекты не были тронуты, щас пойду читать про vsc. К счастью почти все восстановил

Comment: @Bad_m, _"при чем некоторые проекты не были тронуты"_ - это странно. Если ты их выкачивал из гита (git clone), то возможно, они на самом деле не "не были тронуты", а вернулись к тому состоянию, в котором ты их выкачал. А вообще, несколько странно открывать корневую папку с разными проектами в одном VS Code'е.